# How can I possibly do this kind of noise effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, noise

Do you know how can I apply this kind of noise effect? (image attached)
Seems like it somehow needs some gradients for that to have the effect, any help would be really appreciated, thank you!
(Illustration is not mine)
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Treat this like high school math class - show us your work.

Comment: Here's another post on how to achieve this style: [**How to get speckled shading in Photoshop?**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/25653/8708)

Comment: Scott & Ryan, sorry for not following the rules but hopefully thanks alot @JohnB for referring the relevant question including the answer with it!

Comment: @Ryan I have tried to add a noise effect with a gradient on it but before that, I cannot do the same noise as the one illustration above showing huge and tiny marks on the deep parts of the character previewing as a shadow but anyway thanks alot for the help, I managed to get it on the question provided by JohnB!